# How to work past "You cannot visit ... right now because its certificate has been revoked. "

Tags: google-chrome

My local vagrant box is no longer reachable by chrome with the error

> You cannot visit mysite.local right now because its certificate has
> been revoked.

I have no particular interest in hardening that box, as all developed code goes via git to bare metal that has little in common with the vagrant. How can I tell Chrome to skip that check (ideally on all local and dev subdomains)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you see the message "Your connection is not private", click somewhere on the page and then type the following:

```
thisisunsafe
```

This will bypass the warning.

Comment: This also works in edge chromium, so might work in all the chromium family browsers

Comment: Where do you type this?